# For DevOps Release, how to config pubxml and password to deploy to Azure App Service?

Tags: devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, pubxml, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

In Devops. I'm trying to deploy a project in to Azure web app.
How to use publish profile password?

---

> [image: DevOps capture]

---

The help message doesn't give me any help too...

> [image: Help Message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PublishProfilePassword`(Publish profile password) : The password for the profile file. Consider storing the password in a secret variable and using that variable here. Example: $(Password).

Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops#prerequisites-for-the-task).

The downloaded publishing profile contains your password in the `userPWD` variable.

[image]

For details ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-azure?view=vs-2019#create-the-publish-settings-file-in-azure-app-service).

Comment: Thank you and I actually found the password should be set as here. And I can get the real password from the publish profile.

Answer (score -1):

I found config the password on variable tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Finally I didn't found a resolve for this question.
I used FTP to upload the deploy target files..